# JQuery not running?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey I'm new to jquery and for some reason my jquery isn't running when I open my website. I made sure I have the correct file name and everything. Any ideas? Here is my jquery code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".GameArea").hide();
  });
     });
```

Here is my html code

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="JScript.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: The GameArea is a class defined in the html. I believe I did this correctly? I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: You only need one of `});`

Comment: Please include you body html

Comment: Check your browsers console output and maybe post it here :)

Comment: I got rid of the second });, still didn't work. ):

Comment: Yes, everything should work but it's not for some reason. I have no idea why.

Comment: Is the JS file sitting in the root with the html?

Comment: Yes it is. It is in the same root folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `});` in your code. Additionally, make sure to check inspector's console before posting issues here.  Frequently nothing happens when you have a JavaScript error.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".GameArea").hide();
});
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script 
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


        </head>
        <div class="GameArea">Testing</div>
```

Comment: Please do not answer typo questions. Close them as typo. And guys, for heaven's sake, don't encourage answers like this by upvoting them.

Comment: It is not a typo. The code still doesn't work...

Comment: @Nb179  What does console show?  Additionally, did you typo teh class name?  jQuery is case sensitive.

Comment: I went to the console and it is completely empty. It must be a basic thing I'm missing but not sure what.

Comment: Could you put all your code into a jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Yeah I did. The images in the game area are still showing up there.

Comment: Okay it works now. I had something else in the js file and got rid of it. Thanks for the help.